# Auto white balancing for camera

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, camera-calibration

I am developing a sample camera and I am able to control image sensor directly. The sensors gives out Bayer image and I need to do show images as live view.

I looked at debayering codes and also white balancing. Is there any library in C/C++ that can help me in this process?

Since I need to have live view,  I need to do these things very fast and hence I need algorithms that are very fast.

For example, I can change the RGB gains on sensor and hence I need an algorithm that act at that level, instead of acting on generated image.

Is there any library that help to save images in raw format?

Comment: Even if it doesn't support white balancing, OpenCV is a great C++ library to manipulate images and videos streams.

Answer (score 1):

simplecv has a function for white balance control:

[simplecv project web site](http://simplecv.org/)